# Convert MobileNet from Keras to Tensorflow Lite

Tags: machine-learning, flutter, keras, mobilenet, tensorflow-lite

I'm using Keras 2.2.5, Tensorflow 1.15.0 and I want to convert MobileNet to Tensorflow Lite in order to use in flutter app:
[my code in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44463.png)

I've tried everything but still got this stuck

```py
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D, ReLU
from pathlib import Path
from keras.models import model_from_json
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import CustomObjectScope

model_architecture = '/content/model_mobilenet.json'
model_weights = '/content/weights-improvement-42-0.03.hdf5'

model_structure = Path(model_architecture).read_text()

with CustomObjectScope({'relu6': ReLU ,'DepthwiseConv2D': DepthwiseConv2D}):
    model = model_from_json(model_structure)
    model.load_weights(model_weights)
```

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

and the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-136d2dc1e3d0> in <module>()
     10 
     11 with CustomObjectScope({'relu6': ReLU ,'DepthwiseConv2D': DepthwiseConv2D}):
---> 12     model = model_from_json(model_structure)
     13     model.load_weights(model_weights)
     14 

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    165             if fn is None:
    166                 raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name +
--> 167                                  ':' + function_name)
    168         return fn
    169     else:

ValueError: Unknown activation function:relu6
```

Comment: Could you please share at least some of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: I've added all the code.